# Inability to filter number and Duplication of BookingID

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day all. I am new to Ms access, just trying my hands on projects and I have run into a problem on one of my applications. I created  an Hotel Management system and after creating it, I intended to filter out just debtors so I created a query called QRYBALANCELIST but I don't seem to use filter criteria <>0 to help me on that.

secondly, another problem I encountered is duplication of BookingID on my payment query as i want it to just update last payment balance after a new payment but it keeps on listing it. The name of the query is qryBookingPayments which is the record source of form is named frmBookingPaymentextendedDS

Please i would be glad if someone could help review these problems for me.

Comment: Please do not include attachments to external files in your question. Instead, include any relevant code in your question.

Comment: You should probably go to a forum that has facility for attaching and downloading files.